# Javascript While loop condition with no-cond-assign error

Tags: javascript, eslint

**Error:** Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment. (`no-cond-assign`)

```js
const re = /<%([^%>]+)?%>/g;
let match;
while (match = re.exec('<%hello%> you <%!%>')) {
  console.log(match);
}
```

Doing a `while` loop to reassign match, but getting `no-cond-assign` error. I can still get output without errors but what is the best way to correct the syntax? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use a `do-while` loop instead, so you can `break` inside a `while(true)`:

```js
const re = /<%([^%>]+)?%>/g;
while (true) {
  const match = re.exec('<%hello%> you <%!%>');
  if (!match) {
    break;
  }
  console.log(match);
}
```

IMO, this situation is the *one* time in Javascript where assignment inside a conditional (in your original code) is clearer than the alternative. I wouldn't be afraid of disabling that linting rule for this one line.

Assuming you want to retrieve the first capturing group, you'll be able to use [string.prototype.matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) in modern environments:

```js
const str = '<%hello%> you <%!%>';
const contentInsidePercents = [...str.matchAll(/<%([^%>]+)?%>/g)]
  .map(match => match[1]);
console.log(contentInsidePercents);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Doesn't `do-while` duplicate `.exec` call?

Comment: Oh, you're right, guess the `while(true)` is the way to go

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use

```
while ((match = re.exec('<%hello%> you <%!%>'))!== null)
```

```js
const re = /<%([^%>]+)?%>/g;
let match;
while ((match = re.exec('<%hello%> you <%!%>'))!== null) {
  console.log(match);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `no-cond-assign` prohibits assignment inside a conditional

Comment: @CertainPerformance it prohibits assignment expression here it is actually conditional statement, you can see [Demo](https://eslint.org/demo/)

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thought evaluating an assignment as an expression was prohibited (it looks like an easy source of bugs) but I'm not seeing anything against it in the built-in rules.

Comment: Thanks! This is looking neat and an easy solution

Comment: It looks to be prohibited in tslint's `no-conditional-assignment`, but not in eslint's `no-cond-assign`, despite the very similar sounding names :)

Comment: Well, for having an error free line of code, then I picked @CertainPerformance's answer, since there is `no-conditional-assignment` error in tslint. But this is a neat fix if careless about tslint. Thanks!